# Tomcat is not starting after installing Mifos on Windows using Xampp. Mifos doesn't work, what is wrong?

Tags: xampp, financial, bank, mifos

I am trying to install Mifos in Windows 10 using Xampp 5.6.8. I tried all the steps given in Mifos documentation but now Tomcat server does not start. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the tomcat error?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It was an problem with installed jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the right versions of TomCat and JDK

For example the required version of Tomcat: *Tomcat 7* , JAVA   : *JDK-8u271*

Regards.